# Trouble trying to retrieve data from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this piece of working code that saves data to Firebase:

```
let locRef = locationRef.childByAutoId()
let locItem = [
    senderId : [
        "location": getLocationID()
    ]
]

locRef.setValue(locItem)
```

And I want to retrieve the user's (identified by senderID) "location", so I tried this piece of code:

```
locationRef.child("location").child(senderId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.locationId = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

However my app is crashing when the piece of code is run, and there are no errors. I think my mistake may be that `.child("location")` must be something else, but I do not know what.

Database structure (JSON):

```
{
  "locations" : {
    "-KLEdoj2eiF7EW9m0815" : {
      "W6vSOHZLTwNM33JYqkKHvaIVRF13" : {
        "location" : "Seattle, WA"
      }
    },
    "-KLLfcOvYHwIufBALM0-" : {
      "W6vSOHZLTwNM33JYqkKHvaIVRF13" : {
        "location" : "London, United Kingdom"
      }
    },
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: could you describe how exactly your database schema is structured? you can find a JSON export file in database -> data. Please attach it to your question so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: how are you declaring `locationRef`?

Comment: `var locationRef: FIRDatabaseReference!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be referring to your location as the following

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("locations").child(locationId).child(senderId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.location = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
}
```

For example:

If you have `locationId = "-KLEdoj2eiF7EW9m0815"` and `senderId = "W6vSOHZLTwNM33JYqkKHvaIVRF13"` the above call will set the `self.location` to `"Seattle, WA"`

Comment: Sorry, the above code does not work...I'm super confused because locationID the variable that I am setting the retrieved data too, why are you calling `.child(locationID)`?

Comment: @AhadSheriff I named it `locationId` because looking into the database tree you attached you have Ids inside your `/locations` branch. (i'm assuming your working with `/location/locationId/senderId`) or what is the ids you are storing inside `/locations`?